# Can we add a link to the chat "FAQ" page in the description of the privilege?

Tags: feature-request, chat, help-center, privileges-page

A lot of new chat users (myself included) begin by asking someone in the room how to use the chat system. I think an easy-to-find link to the chat "Frequently Asked Questions" page would help people feel more comfortable. There is a link in the chat room itself, but it's in tiny blue lower-case letters at the bottom of the page.

I propose adding a link on the Help Center > Privileges page, in the description of the privilege. It would look something like this:

20 **talk in chat** Participate in this site's [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting) rooms.